# Ember: Dynamically generate link-to html

Tags: javascript, string, ember.js, rendering, handlebars.js

I have a standard way in my ember app to display alert messages. I just pass it a string.

But now I want to include an ember link inside my message.

This is not working:

```
  afterModel: function(model) {
     if (model.length) {
        this.send("addAlert", "Click {{#link-to 'reviews.show' 1}}here{{/link-to}} to see the review");
     }
  }
```

This is how the html is rendered:

```
{{#each alerts as |alert|}}
  <div data-alert class="alert-box {{alert.state}} radius">
    {{{alert.message}}}
      <a class="close" {{action 'removeAlert' alert}}>x&nbsp;</a>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

With a handlebars tripple-thing `{{{}}}`

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps a helper method where you pass the route name and params?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean. Give an example? @JordyLangen